# Static files not loading in django

Tags: django

i'm trying to serve my static files, in my localhost was fine but now in production it doesnt work. my files are like these:

```
mysitename/
    myappname/
    mysitename/
    static/
    manage.py
```

and in my `settings.py` i'm setting this config:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/full/path/to/mysitename/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = ('/full/path/to/mysitename/static')
```

i'm using a 3rd party server so i dont have sudo access

thanks

Comment: Have you any command line access? It doesn't need to be sudo access

Comment: Have you read the documentation on deploying? In particular, have you set up your production server to actually serve the static files?

Comment: How can I do this @DanielRoseman? I'm not the owner of the server, they give me the server ready to use. But I've tried in many ways, setting STATIC_ROOT to my static folder, but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

In a production server Django doesn't automatically serve images.

You have to set up the production server to serve these files.

Read the docs on [deploying Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/)